# Stop Propagation is not working as expected when mouse over and out event execute several times

Tags: jquery

Stop Propagation is not working as expected when mouse over and out event execute several times.

Initially code is working perfectly. But, when user mouse over and out two-three times at once on `test link` at that time background shadow is not appearing.

Here is my code and [FIDDLE LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/xm5vq0ej/2/)

JQUERY:

```
$(document).on('mouseover mouseleave', ".link", function (ev) {
    $mouse_is_inside = ev.type;
    (($mouse_is_inside==="mouseover")?$("#backdrop").addClass("active").fadeIn(function(){
    }):$("#backdrop").fadeOut(function(){
        $(this).removeClass("active");
        ev.stopPropagation();
    }));            
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="link">
   <a href="#" class="link"> Test </a>
</div>
<div id="backdrop"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#backdrop.active {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
.link {
    background: #CCC;
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 12;
}
```

Comment: Try mouseenter instead of mouseover

Comment: @LShetty : Same problem in mouseenter event

Answer (score 1):

How about doing it with just CSS? Bear in mind that this would only work on modern browsers such as Chrome, FF, Safari and IE10+

```
    #backdrop {
        opacity: 0;
        transition: opacity 300ms ease-in;
        /* vendor prefixes :) */
    }
    .link {
        background: #CCC;
        height: 300px;
        width: 300px;
        display: block;
        position: relative;
        z-index: 12;
    }
    .link:hover + #backdrop {
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
        opacity: 1;
        height: 100%;
        left: 0;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%;
    }
```

Demo@[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xm5vq0ej/1/)

Comment: Undoubtedly, this is a nice solution(deserves 1 upvote too), But, I'm doing something big. Here i've give just demonstration. My actual structure is something more difficult. The backdrop and <a> link is not neighbor in my original structure.

Comment: Check I've edited my Html structure. Now, this css solution will not work